# increasing fraction digits (decimal points) in anylogic

Tags: decimal, anylogic

[image]

By result I mean these values which are shown in this picture which are related to variables and statistics. Every time I run the model I get the results up to only 3 decimal places that I want to increase them in to 6 decimal places. I hope I could clearly state what I mean this time.

Answer (score 0):

Anylogic truncates the visible value to 3 decimal places. if you want more you should read you data in some other way:

- export it to a text file
- output it to the console with: `traceln(varname)`
- use the text-object to display the value

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: if it answered your question, then please mark it as "answered"